# Не могу использовать «let» в visual studio 2012

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

Ковыряю один проект на vs 2012. Так вот хочу кое-что дописать, но js интерпретатор не понимает директиву `let`. Вернее он ее выделяет цветом все как положено, но не может выполнить обычное присвоение `let a = 1;` 
Понимаю что можно `var` использовать, но мне принципиально.

Comment: Так происходит потому, что const и let появились в ES2015.

Comment: @Qwerty_Wasd, печально. Спасибо.